# Using toString function in R

Tags: r, tostring

I have numeric objects a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4. Now when I use :

```
toString(c(a,b,c,d))
```

I get:

```
"1, 2, 3, 4"
```

as the output. How do I get rid of the **comma**? I want "1234" as the output. Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `paste` or `paste0`:

```
a <- 1; b <- 2; c <- 3; d <- 4
paste0(a, b, c, d)
# [1] "1234"
paste(a, b, c, d, sep="")
# [1] "1234"
```

---

You cannot get the result directly from `toString` even though `toString` uses `paste` under the hood:

```
toString.default
# function (x, width = NULL, ...) 
# {
#     string <- paste(x, collapse = ", ")
# --- function continues ---
```

Compare that behavior with:

```
paste(c(a, b, c, d), collapse = ", ")
# [1] "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Since it is hard-coded, if you really wanted to use `toString`, you would have to then use `sub`/`gsub` to remove the "`,`" after you used `toString`, but that seems inefficient to me.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Is there anyway I can remove comma from toString() ?

Comment: @AmanMathur, Do the same thing. Wrap it in `paste` or `paste0`. `paste` is the function you are looking for and `toString` isn't really necessary here.

Comment: @AmanMathur, look at the source to `toString.default` and you will see that it just calls `paste` with `collapse` hard-coded as `", "`.